# Dealing with Angular 4 Lifecycle Hooks

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, dom

So I'm doing DOM manipulations using a scroll library and one of the things I needed to do is calculate the end of the animation based on the position of DOM elements on my component. The problem is when I try to get the height of an element it doesn't give me the right height.

It's weird with the lifecycle hooks because currently I have it at AfterViewInit and I've tried AfterContentInit but this only works when I put it in AfterViewChecked and wait until the 50th time it runs.

So the question is, is there a best practice for waiting till all of the DOM completes in Angular? Or is just doing this workaround the only way. Seems really a bad way to go about this...

Answer (score 0):

This is probably still not the best fix, but I'm currently using $(document).ready() on ngOnInit to somewhat achieve this result. Of course you would need to use jQuery.